# Time complexity of a function with two recursive calls that divide N in half

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o

```
int function8(int N) {
  int sum = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) sum += 1;
  
  if (N > 1)
    return sum + function8(N / 2) + function8(N / 2);
  else
    return 0;
}
```

What is the time complexity of the above algorithm?

Referring to the Fibonacci recursion theory, I consider this as N*2^N. Because the `for` loop is O(N) and the recursion part is 2^N.

Answer (score 1):

> the recursion part is 2^N

No, the recursion part is O(log(N)) because N is chopped in half for each recursive call. The algorithm basically reduces to [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), O(n log(n)), because we do O(N) work per stack frame and there are log(N) stack frames created.

Fibonacci is unrelated here since that's a dynamic programming problem that involves using the previous two solutions N-1 and N-2 to build N which gives a naive exponential algorithm as you say. That's a different complexity class than [divide & conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) as in the code we're looking at here. If the recursive calls were `function8(N - 2) + function8(N - 1);`, then you'd be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of your implementation is `O(N log N)` since the recurrence relation is `T(N) = O(N) + 2 * T(N/2)` (`O(N)` for computing `sum`, and the rest for the two recursive calls).

But instead of `function8(N / 2) + function8(N / 2)` you could have written `2 * function8(N / 2)`. This would give you the recurrence relation `T(N) = O(N) + T(N/2)` (only one recursive call),
thereby reducing the complexity to `O(N)`.